# Beginning a sentence with "being"

Tags: adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

Is the sentence below grammatically correct?

> Being so many people ill, I have cancelled the meeting.

If not, please explain the grammar behind it.

Answer (score 2):

The usual pattern when beginning a sentence with *being* is

> **Being that** *and the reason*
>
> *Being that* so many people are ill...
>   *Being that* the weather is so hot...

which has a similar understanding as *because*

> *Because* so many people are ill...
>   *Because* the weather is so hot...

Comment: Alternately, *So many people being ill...*

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not acceptable. There are a few alternatives, but if you want to retain the gerund-participial clause you need "there" as subject:

> *There being so many people ill, I have cancelled the meeting*.

.